# AND or OR gene - protein logical relation in KEGG

Tags: gene, kegg

How do I know if it is a AND or OR relationship between genes associated with the same enzyme in KEGG? E.g., for EC:1.6.1.2 (http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ec:1.6.1.2) does the bacterium *Streptomyces coelicolor* (SCO) need SCO7622 AND SCO7623 or SCO7622 OR SCO7623? [image]

Answer (score 1):

The enzyme EC:1.6.1.2 is an NAD(P) transhydrogenase and consists of two subunits. The two subunits are encoded by two different genes [pntA](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?sco+SCO7623) and [pntB](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?sco:SCO7622).

So in terms of computer logic I would say AND, both subunits are necessary for a functional NAD(P) transhydrogenase enzyme (EC:1.6.1.2).

Comment: This was only an example, is there a way of knowing in general?

Comment: With enzymes from KEGG there is not, I am afraid. In your example it becomes clear that we see 2 subunits, and hence form the same protein. However, if you look for example at human isocitrate dehydrogenase (IDH) [EC 1.1.1.42](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ec:1.1.1.42), you will see that two different genes (IDH1 and IDH2) are listed. These 2 genes are not subunits of the same protein but are 2 different proteins (one in mitochondrium and the other in cytosol). With KEGG the interest in enzyme, not gene.